# bash kill parent process and all its children

Tags: bash, docker, kill

I'm using a shell script *input.sh* which calls a docker container. 
Let's that my script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

input_variable_docker=folder

docker run -t --rm -v /mnt/data/:/home/user/data/ -e INPUT_IMAGE=$input_variable_docker my_process /home/desuser/processing_scripts/run_script_docker.sh
```

Once I run the *input.sh* script, the docker container is deployed and it does its processes.

How could I kill both the parent script:*input.sh* and all the processes called by the docker?

If I get the PID from *ps ux* and I do

```
kill -9 $PID
```

I'm able to kill the *input.sh* script but all the the docker porcesses are still running.

Thanks

Comment: The container doesn't run as a spawned process, but instead is handled by the docker daemon. You should give the container a specific `name` and use a bash trap to `docker rm -f name`. Don't use `kill -9` in this scenario as this cannot be trapped.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Could you please give me an example of how to set this trap?

Comment: `trap "docker rm -f name" SIGINT SIGTERM` - ensure this runs before your docker run.